# Django and django rest framework storing binary image and convert to image

Tags: django, image, binary, django-rest-framework

I am using django to create API only and i am working together with my partner to integrate with his IOS phone. He told me that the image he sent will be in byte/binary format. And then i have to convert that binary data into image ? 
Also, the bigger the size of the image, the larger it is ? As i am not sure if i am storing in byte or byte array.

This is the first time i heard of using about being able to store binary/byte and convert it to image. As i only know about using ImageField to store image. There are also very limited post regarding on storing image in byte and the conversion. Even the django documentation on BinaryField is very limited

There is also a third party package which help the conversion but i have no idea on how to use it as there isnt much documentation on how to use it on the API.

source: https://github.com/JeffreyATW/binaryimage

I know this may be asking a lot but please help me

Here is my code currently:

**models.py**

```
class MyUser(AbstractUser):
    userId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=6, blank=True, null=True)
    nric = models.CharField(max_length=9, blank=True, null=True)
    birthday = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    birthTime = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.BinaryField()
```

**serializer.py**

```
class UserCreate2Serializer(ModelSerializer):
    email = EmailField(label='Email Address')
    valid_time_formats = ['%H:%M', '%I:%M%p', '%I:%M %p']
    birthTime = serializers.TimeField(format='%I:%M %p', input_formats=valid_time_formats, allow_null=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = ['username', 'password', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'gender', 'nric', 'birthday', 'birthTime', 'image']
        extra_kwargs = {"password": {"write_only": True}}

    def validate(self, data):  # to validate if the user have been used
        email = data['email']
        user_queryset = MyUser.objects.filter(email=email)
        if user_queryset.exists():
            raise ValidationError({"email": "This user has already registered."})
        return data

    # Custom create function
    def create(self, validated_data):
        username = validated_data['username']
        password = validated_data['password']
        email = validated_data['email']
        first_name = validated_data['first_name']
        last_name = validated_data['last_name']
        gender = validated_data['gender']
        nric = validated_data['nric']
        birthday = validated_data['birthday']
        birthTime = validated_data['birthTime']
        image = validated_data['image']

        user_obj = MyUser(
            username = username,
            email = email,
            first_name = first_name,
            last_name = last_name,
            gender = gender,
            nric = nric,
            birthday = birthday,
            birthTime = birthTime,
            image = image,
        )
        user_obj.set_password(password)
        user_obj.save()
        return validated_data
```

**views.py**

```
class CreateUser2View(CreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    serializer_class = UserCreate2Serializer
    queryset = MyUser.objects.all()

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        if not serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=False):
            return Response({"promptmsg": "You have failed to register an account",
                             "status": "400"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        # serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response({"promptmsg": "You have successfully register",
                         "status": "200"}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

Comment: uhm, what?  I suggest you look at this for a usage example. https://github.com/ChristianKreuzberger/django-rest-imageupload-example

Comment: my friend said that the image he sent me is in byte format, does it matter if i use django imagefield instead of binaryfield ? Sorry, i still dont understand how these image upload works